# Parsing C# in scripting language

Tags: c#, python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to write some simple scripts which will parse C# code and modify it or mayby for the begining, pull some interesting parts.

Is there any library for, ex. Python, to do that? I know there are few libraries (in NRefactor there is something to build AST from C#), but i'd like something for script langs - parse and build AST or something like that.

Comment: You can build a parser in Python just fine. But C# is not exactly a simple language (e.g. contextual keywords), and quite a few steps that may fall under "refactoring" benefit from further comprehension of the code (e.g. type information). So your best bet may be trying to re-use existing solutions.

Comment: You might want to look at the Roslyn CTP http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx. It aspires to be an API to do exactly what you describe.

Comment: You should be able to use NRefactory from IronPython without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this exists for Python.  Nor do I understand your "script" langauge constraint; Python is a full language.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C# Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) can parse C# in its various dialects including C# 4.0, build ASTs, and renerate valid C# code from those ASTs.

The DMS machinery will let you procedurally visit/inspect/modify the ASTs using DMS's "scripting" language, PARLANSE.   Or you can use DMS's ability to apply [pattern-directed source-to-source program transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) written directly using C# syntax to help you make changes to the AST more conveniently.

Comment: I needed simple tool to create fast scripts which i could run inside IDE (ex. VisualStudio) and for example refactor some small amount of code according to company's conventions. And right now this conventions are changing too often and such tools could speed up whole process

Comment: I doubt you are going to get "simple" tool to "refactor" code.   Code is complex and the semantics have to be understood and preserved.